# Fancy box gallery, delete element from HTML on Delete button click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, onclick, fancybox

I have a galery, when is clicked on the image, fancy box shows up. There is a delete button with on click event:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".previewPhoto").on("click", function () {
                var photo = $(this).data('photo'),
                id = $(this).data('id'),
                link = 'http://domain.com/members/photos/' + id + '/' + photo;
                $.fancybox({
                    'padding'       : 0,
                    'href'          : link,
                    'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                    'titlePosition' : 'over',
                    'title' : '<button class="deleteP">Delete</button>',
                    'onComplete': function() {
                        $(".deleteP").click(function() {
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'ajax/deletePhoto.php',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: {deletephoto:true, photo:photo}, 
                                success: function (result) {
                                    $.fancybox.close();
                                    $('li#'+photo).remove();
                                    $.msg('Photo Deleted!');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    }
            });
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <li id="9O9x5Ww0o8NOQ.jpg"><img data-id="29" data-photo="9O9x5Ww0o8NOQ.jpg" class="previewPhoto" src="http://domain.com/members/photos/29/9O9x5Ww0o8NOQ.jpg" width="140" height="116" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Delete button on click event works(fancybox is closed on click), but li element is not deleted from HTML. Something is wrong with - $('li#'+photo).remove(); How could I change it if I want to delete li element?

Comment: what you get as photo inside inside the success callback.. alert and check it out..

Comment: alert(photo); - 9O9x5Ww0o8NOQ.jpg

Comment: it is better to avoid special operators while defining ids of an element... in you case.. in `.jpg` `.` is a class selector so the selector fails to select the element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to remove ".jpg" from the id, the "." will make the selector look for li#9O9x5Ww0o8NOQ.jpg which would be

```
<li id="9O9x5Ww0o8NOQ" class="jpg"/>
```

and does not exist.

Comment: Thank You :), but I have implemented differently. t.parent().remove();
when t = $(this).

Answer (score -1):

What is shown if you add `alert(photo);` before `$('li#'+photo).remove();`??

If it's empty, try to remove the `var` at the beginning of `var photo = $(this).data('photo'),`

Sometimes, you have to use `[type="value"]` for selector, if you can have some sepcial chars. So try to replace your selector by :

```
$('li[id="'+photo+'"]').remove();
```